# SharePoint list shows circles on columns heading when added fabric css

Tags: sharepoint-online, css, spfx-extensions

SharePoint list shows circles(or dots) on columns heading If I add fabric css from SPFX Application Customizer. How can I fix that issue?

[image]

Comment: Where have you applied the css? can you please add the css code you are using to your question?

Comment: Thanks Ganesh for the response. I have imported the css file from SCSS file by @import '~@fluentui/react/dist/css/fabric.css'